# Node.js: How to create file with 755 permissions with fs.createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Which flag do I need to use in Nodes `fs.createWriteStream` to make it create files with 755 permissions.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options You can follow this link and you will get all the information

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set permissions with `createWriteStream`, using the `mode` option:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('hello.js', { mode: 0o755 });
stream.write("#!/usr/bin/node\n");
stream.write("console.log('hello world');");
stream.end();
```

This will create a file called `hello.js` with the mode set to 755 permissions.

Comment: It's correct, `mode` takes in a number, and in this case, I'm using an octal number for permissions, since that's how permissions like 755 are usually represented in UNIX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_modes

Comment: Ahh, I was unaware that `0o644` is a valid octal notation. Carry on. :)